# Creating a sample rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

How to create a sample rake task in spree and run it. I have tried to create a rake task in different locations like /backend/lib/tasks  /sample/lib/tasks /sandbox/lib/tasks , but when i run the rake task from command line I get the error dont kow how to build a rake task. I am using a sandbox application

Comment: Can you share more details, not sure what you meant by sandbox application?

Comment: You generally define Rake tasks in your Rakefile (or in rakelib/ from whence they get auto-imported). If you're doing it in a different place, you need to load them somehow.

Comment: spree is basically an ecommerce gem . it has four folders Api,backend,frontend and  core. All of these folders have rails structure in it(i.e app,bin,config etc..). and there is an option to create sandbox application for testing purpose.In my case i created rake task in all the folders incuding sandbox one.(i.e  in both rakefile and lib/tasks) but when i run rake --tasks . I am unable to see the task created by me